# If $R^*(R+S)\equiv S^*(R+S)$, then $R^*\equiv S^*$

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, regular-expressions

If $R^*(R+S)\equiv S^*(R+S)$, then $R^*\equiv S^*$

I have to prove whether this is true or false.

Right now I think it's true, because I can't really think of a counter example. This is where I got:

$R^*(R+S)\equiv S^*(R+S)$, then $R^*\equiv S^*$ means

$$L(R^*)L(R+S)= L(S^*)L(R+S)$$

Where $(*)$ is the Kleene star and $L(R)$ means language denoted by $R$.

Don't really know if we can "cross out" on languages, since the $L(R+S)$ in common on both sides, our expression becomes

$$L(R^*)= L(S^*)$$

which means $R^*\equiv S^*$

would this be correct? The only step I am unsure about is when I "cross out" $L(R+S)$ since it is common on both sides.

Comment: @user76284 that's what I'm asking. Why can I just "cancel" it?

Comment: I think you could rephrase it in properly qualified terms of sets of strings and string concatenation, then prove it in terms of set equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $R$ is $\{\epsilon\}$ and $S$ is $\{a\}^*$.

Now $R^* = R$ and $S^* = SS = S$.

Also $(R+T) = RT = T$ for any $T$.

So $R^*(R+S) = S^*(R+S) = S$, but $R^* \ne S^*$

Comment: How does $S^*=S$?

Comment: @ksplitx: The Kleene closure of a Kleene closure is the original closure. Or, to put it another way, $S$ is any number of $a$s, so any repetition of $S$ is still some number of $a$s, and is therefore in $S$.

Comment: okay, and for your last line, if we have $S^*(R+S)$, then this simplifies to $S^* S$.

So does $S^* S=S$? Why..

because $S={a}^*=\{\epsilon,a,aaa,\dots\}$, but $S^* S$ does not include $\epsilon$ since we are always concatenating an $a$

Comment: @ksplitx: $\epsilon \in S$ so we are *not* always concatenating an $a$.

Comment: this is true, thanks. but answering my original question, does this mean that we cannot "cancel" common terms as I did?>

Comment: @ksplitx left/right derivative does not preserve inequality, so the factoring you attempted is not valid, and my simple example should shiq you why.